# Best engine Oil for TVS Apache RTR 160 4V?

Tags: engine, oil, apache-rtr

I have been using the TVS's own Tru4 Synthetic oil but i think the quality of that oil is not that great (Maybe am wrong), please suggest me a good engine oil for my  bike.

Thanks.

Comment: What symptoms are abnormal ? How old, how many 1000km / oil change, how hot is engine from driving? How long do you want till engine overhaul?

Comment: Currently am having no problem but the oil that mentioned is costly almost 2X as that of castrol's that's why i was thinking to use other oil brands because of the prices.

Comment: Castrol® POWER1?  ok

Comment: Fully synthetic might be better but clean semisynth oil and filter replaced per guidelines  to reduce wear is adequate depending driving RPM

Comment: usually i drive around 5k RPM, and yes am talking about castrol power 1